# Dummies guide to mailutils

Tags: web-services, shell, email, command-line

As a prelude to learning more about postfix and dovecot (as a pure hobbyist) I'm trying to understand the mailutils package. I'm using Davmail so I have the server set up at localhost and my mailutils.rc looks like the following.

```
program mail.mailutils{
mailbox {
  mailbox-pattern "maildir///home/tahnoon/var/mail/${user}";
};   
mailer {
  url smtp://localhost:1025;
}   
server localhost:1110 {
  pop3d 'daemon';
  foreground 'false';
  port 1110;
}    
};
```

But it doesn't seem to do anything. I'm struggling with the manual for mailutils a little and I wondered if there was an alternate source for information or a walkthrough on how to set up mailutils to work with a specific smtp and pop server.

Any thoughts on what this config file should look like would be the second half of my question.

Thanks

Comment: Good question! +1  I've been searching for a couple of days, and haven't found anything ***useful*** - as in a *'Dummies Guide'*.